# java vlcj long delay before video starts playing

Tags: java, windows, video, mp4, vlcj

I'm experiencing a big delay, quite often up to half a minute before video starts playing. I'm using maven dependency library groupID: **uk.co.caprica**, artifactId **vlcj**, **version3.10.1**, **vlc 3.0.1 Vetinari** installed and mp4 video. Log hangs for a while between:

**15:40:40.222 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer - Raising event for new media**

and
**15:41:03.047 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer - play()**

Code sample:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("vlcj Tutorial");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent videoCanvas = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
    p.add(videoCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setLocation(100, 100);
    frame.setSize(1050, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    player = videoCanvas.getMediaPlayer();
    player.prepareMedia("C:\\Users\\Kamil\\Documents\\video\\25.mp4");
    player.parseMedia();
    player.play();
```

> 15:40:40.211 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG
>   u.c.c.v.p.e.DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer - enableOverlay(enable=true)
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   prepareMedia(mrl=C:\Users\Kamil\Documents\video\25.mp4,mediaOptions=[])
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.MediaResourceLocator -
>   encodeMrl(mrl=C:\Users\Kamil\Documents\video\25.mp4)
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.MediaResourceLocator -
>   MRL does not contain any Unicode characters
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.MediaResourceLocator -
>   result=C:\Users\Kamil\Documents\video\25.mp4
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   prepareMedia(media=SimpleMedia[mrl=C:\Users\Kamil\Documents\video\25.mp4,mediaOptions=[Ljava.lang.String;@47722435])
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   setMedia(media=SimpleMedia[mrl=C:\Users\Kamil\Documents\video\25.mp4,mediaOptions=[Ljava.lang.String;@47722435])
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   deregisterMediaEventListener()
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   event=libvlc_MediaMetaChanged
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   event=libvlc_MediaSubItemAdded
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   event=libvlc_MediaDurationChanged
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   event=libvlc_MediaParsedChanged
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   event=libvlc_MediaFreed
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   event=libvlc_MediaStateChanged
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   event=libvlc_MediaSubItemTreeAdded
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   createMediaInstance(media=SimpleMedia[mrl=C:\Users\Kamil\Documents\video\25.mp4,mediaOptions=[Ljava.lang.String;@47722435])
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   Treating mrl as a path
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   mediaInstance=native@0x245e2850
>   (uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.internal.libvlc_media_t@245e2850)
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   registerMediaEventListener()
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   event=libvlc_MediaMetaChanged
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   result=0
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   event=libvlc_MediaSubItemAdded
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   result=0
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   event=libvlc_MediaDurationChanged
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   result=0
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   event=libvlc_MediaParsedChanged
>
> 15:40:40.221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   result=0
>
> 15:40:40.222 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   event=libvlc_MediaFreed
>
> 15:40:40.222 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   result=0
>
> 15:40:40.222 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   event=libvlc_MediaStateChanged
>
> 15:40:40.222 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   result=0
>
> 15:40:40.222 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   event=libvlc_MediaSubItemTreeAdded
>
> 15:40:40.222 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   result=0
>
> 15:40:40.222 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   mrl(mediaInstance=native@0x245e2850 
>   (uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.internal.libvlc_media_t@245e2850))
>
> 15:40:40.222 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   result=true
>
> 15:40:40.222 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   parseMedia()
>
> 15:40:40.222 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   mediaChanged(mediaPlayer=uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer@250aa6d9,media=native@0x245e2850
>   (uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.internal.libvlc_media_t@245e2850),mrl=file:///C:/Users/Kamil/Documents/video/25.mp4)
>
> 15:40:40.222 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   Raising event for new media
>
> 15:41:03.047 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   play()
>
> 15:41:03.047 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG
>   u.c.c.v.p.e.DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer - onBeforePlay()
>
> 15:41:03.047 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG
>   u.c.c.v.p.e.DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer - attachVideoSurface()
>
> 15:41:03.047 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.e.v.CanvasVideoSurface
>   - attach()
>
> 15:41:03.047 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.e.v.CanvasVideoSurface
>   - componentId=2693554
>
> 15:41:03.047 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG
>   u.c.c.v.p.e.v.w.WindowsVideoSurfaceAdapter -
>   attach(componentId=2693554)
>
> 15:41:03.047 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.e.v.CanvasVideoSurface
>   - video surface attached
>
> 15:41:03.048 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   after play
>
> 15:41:03.048 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG u.c.c.v.p.DefaultMediaPlayer -
>   addMediaPlayerEventListener(listener=com.xxx.ContentPanel$1@14db5202)

Comment: You should really make an effort to format that log a bit better for readability if you want people to try and help you.

Comment: Hi caprica, I have formated log, added -vvv option to media factory and what I have notice, when I will comment parseMedia(), freeze appears around this line: [00000000231f6df0] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module matching "file

Comment: after a while rest of the line: ": 15 candidates
[00000000231f6df0] main demux debug: no access_demux modules matched
[000000002178c8a0] main stream debug: creating access: file:///C:/Users/Kamil/Documents/video/25.mp4 appears

Comment: seems like stepping back to version 3.9.0 of vlcj resolves the problem